# React Native file upload to Spring Undertow Server get error: java.io.IOException: UT000036: Connection terminated parsing multipart data

Tags: spring, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, react-native, undertow

I'm making react native app with spring server. I'm using react native xhr for file upload.

```
 var photo = {
     uri: uriFromCameraRoll,
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     name: 'photo.jpg', };

 var body = new FormData(); body.append('photo', photo);

 xhr.open('POST', serverURL); xhr.send(body);
```

And for spring, I'm using undertow server. But keep getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException: UT000036: Connection terminated parsing multipart
>   data  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:217)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:762)
>     ... 92 common frames omitted

If I use postman or html form submit, there won't be such kinds of problems. And also, if I'm using tomcat or jetty, there won't be such kinds of problems. Is there anyone know how to solve this?

## Update

After a careful debug and compare with several working designs. I found that it's because the boundary generated by xhr has double quote:

```
boundary=""Z3shMls-AQ6eaHSwjw2jzfRcO6-fpHyDYVbHsfSFx9wigmAkmxnOpg5NG/RdsykXIj0xR3""
```

which isn't supported by undertow. Is there any one know how to solve this?

## Solution

Hello, guys. I managed to solve it myself. According to [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) boundary is allowed to have quotes. But undertow doesn't support it until version 1.3.19.Final. I managed to solve it in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"){
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    // Add newer undertow version after spring boot starter
    compile('io.undertow:undertow-core:1.3.19.Final')
}
```

Comment: That might because it sends fixed-length request with wrong content length, which causes write stream end before it completes.

Comment: @Xeijp Thank you very much. I looked into the HttpServerExchange and I do found a difference in Content-Length between failed React Native xmlHttpRequest and successful safari html form. But how could I fix anything like this?